# Can I use Background Intelligent Transfer Service with FTP?

Tags: vb.net, http, ftp, sftp

I am writing an application that gets its data from many small servers (the "servers" are data loggers and the app consumes the data from the loggers).  The data exists as files on the server and I have been using SSH FTP to get the files.  Specifically I'm using the [.NET wrapper for WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)

I have had some problems with this, some transfer fail (while Filezilla succeeds) and it does not report progress.  Also, the downloads can be long due to limited bandwidth at the server.  So I would like to use BITS to do the transfers but it appears this only works with HTTP.  I could switch to HTTP but I currently check what needs to be downloaded by comparing file sizes and dates on the server and the local cache. This does not seem possible using HTTP.

Is there a way to use BITS and FTP?  Or is there a way to check what needs downloading with HTTP?

I have complete control over the servers.  They currently run Linux and OpenSSH to facilitate the transfers.  I'm using VB and .NET framework 4.0 for the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a System.Net.HttpWebRequest to the web URL with a request method of "HEAD".  You can then get a System.Net.HttpWebResponse and check the ContentLength and LastModified properties of the response to compare to the local cache.
e.g.

```
dim request as System.Net.HttpWebRequest
request=System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://...")
request.Method="HEAD"
dim response as System.Net.HttpWebResponse=request.GetResponse
dim fileLength as integer=response.ContentLength
dim fileDate as datetime=response.LastModified
```

obviously, you need to trap for exceptions as the GetResponse might not like it if the file isn't there or the server isn't available, etc.

Hope this helps, Regards, Denver